# Pass parameters to Drupal to Return XML data

Tags: views

Is there a module that allows the user to pass the parameters in `POST` or `GET` form, and Drupal will return in XML.

Like I have a view named `table`. `table` has fields named `account_number` and `device_id`. I would like to pass parameters in URL like

`?view=table&account_number=123&device_id=d12`

Then the Drupal would return in XML based on the searching criteria passed in URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exposing Views as XML is one of the features of the [Views Bonus Pack](http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus) module.  You would lose your idea of using GET parameters, but you can easily build up other paths, pipe in your parameters, and get output as XML.

This is also something that the [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module can handle, but isn't as tightly coupled with views.  This module is very well [documented](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/services), though.  In particular, I suggest reading the REST examples.  This is an add-on, [Services Views](http://drupal.org/project/services_views), that may fit your needs, but I have never tried it.

Comment: I made a custom php file that would allow me to do that, but coding up the SQL query is a pain since D7 set up the database differently. I'm still new to D7, and don't even know what those `drush` commands are. It seems like this would be the easiest way to do it. Do you think writing my own module can achieve my objective as well?

Comment: Yes, a custom module would work too.  You would make a custom hook_menu callback to query the database, build the XML string, call drupal_add_http_header() to set the content type, then return the XML.  You would also have to work through the template system to get everything output properly.  When possible, always try to leverage builtins and well-tested modules before going down the custom module road.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Now I need to learn how to build a module. haha

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Views data export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export). Its very easy to setup. You can as well use the parameters almost the way you wanted - just define the filter on the view.

Comment: yea, I'm trying that out right now. I'm still new to the whole drupal thing. Especially the `drush` confuses me the most.